# AGE question: WITH clause doesn't work with MATCH/WITH

Tags: cypher, apache-age, opencypher

If I have the following query

```
select * from cypher('agload_test_graph', $$
 match (n) with n where n.name='A' return n
$$) as (sp agtype)
```

then `n.name='A'` doesn't work.

but if I remove `with` clause, then it works:

```
select * from cypher('agload_test_graph', $$
 match (n) where n.name='A' return n
$$) as (sp agtype)
```

I tried the example query in age document.

```
SELECT *
FROM cypher('graph_name', $$
    MATCH (david {name: 'David'})-[]-(otherPerson)-[]->()
    WITH otherPerson, count(*) AS foaf
    WHERE foaf > 1RETURN otherPerson.name
    RETURN otherPerson.name
$$) as (name agtype);
```

Answer (score 0):

The where clause after with is ignored. This is one of the issues in Apache Age which is opened on github. [Issue Page](https://github.com/apache/age/issues/394)

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug in AGE which has been fixed in the most recent commit to AGE. Now your query should work as you expect.

Comment: I have pulled the recent commits to my local repository, still the query does not work as expected.

Comment: @ZainabSaad which query did you ran ? Can you paste it here. Thanks.

Comment: I verified, it is working at my end. The example in age documentation is same as in the documenatation of neo4j https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/with/. 

I created the same usecase and ran the query as in age documentation.

`SELECT *
FROM cypher('graph_name', $$
        MATCH (david {name: 'David'})-[]-(otherPerson)-[]->()
        WITH otherPerson, count(*) AS foaf
        WHERE foaf > 1                       
        RETURN otherPerson.name
$$) as (name agtype);` 

And the result is as expected. Andres is returned.

Comment: See output [output](https://i.imgur.com/BYhLI36.png). Also see this [demo](https://i.imgur.com/kErlgOa.png). 

Please make sure to rebuild age extension after pulling, and stop, start the server again before querying to reflect new changes.

Comment: I pulled the changes, then rebuilt AGE using make install, stopped and started the server, dropped the extension age then recreated and loaded it still the query doesn't give the desired output. Query is 
`SELECT * FROM cypher('graph', $$
MATCH (u) WITH u WHERE u.name = 'John'
RETURN u
$$) AS (result agtype);`
But it returns all the vertices
Where am I making the mistake?

Comment: @ZainabSaad That's odd. Can you please try to run this query and see if this works `SELECT * FROM cypher('graph',$$RETURN isEmpty([])$$) AS (b agtype);`. If this works, it would mean that you have age with latest commits because this function was added after the bug fix.

Comment: It gives an error saying `ERROR:  function ag_catalog.age_isempty(agtype) does not exist`. I am assuming what wrong step did i do in pulling the latest commits that caused it. Btw I am on the same database cluster as before pulling the commits.

Comment: Ok so this means age is not built again properly. You should try these steps again.

- git pull
- make PG_CONFIG=/path/to/bin/pg_config install
- Stop and start the server again
- Drop and Create extension again and then retry

Comment: Again did it, still no success

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252271/discussion-between-muhammad-taha-naveed-and-zainab-saad).

Answer (score -1):

**The problem with your first query** is that the `WHERE` clause is **not applied to the n variable** because the `WHERE` clause is used before the `WITH` clause.  By `WITH`clause, a new variable that is a subset of the previous variable is created in Cypher. Any filters added after the the `WITH` clause will be applied to this new variable rather than the original variable. By deleting the `WITH` clause from your second query, the where clause is being applied directly to the n variable, which is what you want.

**The example query in the age document** you provided is a **legitimate** Cypher query. It uses `MATCH` to find a node with the name "David", then it uses  `WITH` clause to create a new variable *otherPerson*, which is the set of nodes nodes connected to the "David" node, and then uses  `count(*)` function to count the number of nodes connected to the "David" node. After this it uses the `WHERE` clause to filter *otherPerson* nodes where the count of their connections is greater than 1 and return their names.